# Prevent sorting on clicking Input Field in Data Table not working

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am using DataTable to display my Data.

**Issue**
Each Column has a Search Field in the Head. But when I click on the input field, it keeps sorting every time I click inside the input field.

**This is what I need**
On Clicking, I don't want the sorting through input box.

**What I have tried isn't working**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell

$('#example thead th').each( function () {

    var title = $(this).text();



    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

} );



var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 20,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;
            $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that.search( this.value ).draw();
                }
            });
        } );

    }

});

} );

</script>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use 2 rows in the header:

- the first one to control ordering/sorting
- another one to display each input field

Then you need to use the [`orderCellsTop`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) option to specify that only the first row should be used to control sorting.

A basic example, would therefore be as follows:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#result-table thead tr").clone(true).appendTo("#result-table thead");
  // add a text input filter to each column of the new row
  $("#result-table thead tr:eq(1) th").each(function (i) {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search '" + title + "' />");
    $("input", this).on( "keyup change", function () {
      if ($("#result-table").DataTable().column(i).search() !== this.value) {
        $("#result-table").DataTable().column(i).search(this.value).draw();
      }
    });
  });

  $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true,
  });

} );
```